# Jbuilder Partials Merge Instead of Nest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

I'm attempting to have a json response that looks like the below:

```
{
    id: 3,
    title: "Magic",
    desc: "A bag of coolness!"
    type: {
        id: 14,
        title: "Dust"
    }
}
```

What I get is:

```
{
    id:14,
    title:"Dust",
    desc:"A bag of coolness!"
    type: null
}
```

The three jbuilder files being used are below:

_item.json.jbuilder

```
json.(item, :id, :title, :desc)
json.type json.partial! item.type
```

show.json.jbuilder

```
json.partial! @item
```

_type.json.jbuilder

```
json.(type, :id, :title)
```

Why is jbuilder merging type and item instead of nesting type? How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To nest a partial, the below code will work:

```
json.type do
    json.partial! item.type
end
```